# Error sending app request: 100 The parameter message is required

Tags: facebook-opengraph

After not getting this to work, I went back to the example published by facebook. Unfortunately, even their example fails. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

curl -X POST -F 'message=Post%20with%20app%20access%20token' -F 'access_token=mytoken' https://graph.facebook.com/545991534/apprequests -k

returns:
{"error":{"Message:"(#100) The parameter message is required","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Okay, I replaced single quotes with double quotes, and got the following back. Still doesn't seem to be working though. {"request":"192998830846523","to":["545991534"]}

Comment: Your example works for me. It's Facebook voodoo.

Comment: Odd, @sqreept would you mind posting the code you used to get the token, maybe it is a token problem, and the error message is wrong?

Comment: I just took a random token I had stored.

Comment: Okay, I replaced single quotes with double quotes, and got the following back. Still doesn't seem to be working though.
{"request":"192998830846523","to":["545991534"]}

Answer (score 1):

Replace single quotes with double quotes, and check your IDs